# Aún no puedo o no sé como validar en cada campo(Username and email)

Tags: java, android-studio, condiciones, validación, android-sqlite

¿Cómo podría anidar otros "if" dentro del "else if" para verificar que el usuario y/o correo que se están ingresando al registrar, ya se encuentran en la base de datos?
Todo lo estoy haciendo desde sqlite y java.
Solo he validado los campos para que no queden vacios.
[image: ToHelp]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] y modifica tu pregunta incluyendo el código en que has trabajado. Las imágenes son buenas para ilustrar problemas **pero no son útiles para revisar código** y de ser posible **no se deben usar**. Los if ... else pueden anidarse cuando se trata de condiciones simultáneas, cuando las condiciones son complementarias (como se ve en tu código) deben cerrarse sin else y validarse por separado una después de otra.

Comment: Tal cual, deberías de ingresar el código porque por imagen se complica

Answer (score 1):

¡Buenas!
Sería buena idea que insertaras el código en la web en lugar de insertar una captura de pantalla.

Puedes realizar una consulta a la base de datos pidiendole el usuario, voy a mostrartelo en  pseudocódigo de manera básica y resumida.

```
CONSULTA(BUSCA USUARIO)
SI EXISTE -> TRUE:
    MOSTRAR "ESTE USUARIO YA ESTÁ REGISTRADO"
SI EXISTE -> FALSE
    "TU CÓDIGO"
```

¡Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 1):

Vengo de tu otra pregunta. Lo que no entiendo es por qué no preguntas directamente a tu BD si el usuario o el email existe...

Así a "bote pronto", sin código ni nada y expresado en palabras, diría que lo único que tienes que hacer es

`if (SELECT * FROM BD where email=emailIntroducido != null || SELECT * FROM BD WHERE user=userIntroducido != null)`-> "tu email/user ya está registrado en nuestra BD, por favor, introduce uno distinto o recupera tu contraseña".

También depende de como tengas tu BD, si tienes campos únicos, siempre puedes intentar añadirlo a tu DB, y si estuviese repetido, en principio tu insertRec te daría error...

No se si es esto realmente lo que buscas.. Déjame un comentario sino a ver si te puedo echar una mano, aunque la verdad soy nuevo en todo esto y no se si estará en mi mano. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Bien, la respuesta que dió el usuario enterior es totalmente válida, en mi caso haría un `Array` con una consulta parametrizada. Para empezar, crearía el `Array` con la consulta en `SQLite` del mail y contraseña:

```
public ArrayList login(String mail, String pass) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.openReadableDB();
    String[] campos = new String[]{ConstantsBD.EMP_ID, ConstantsBD.EMP_MAIL, ConstantsBD.EMP_PASS, demases datos};
    String where = ConstantsBD.EMP_NOM + " = '" + mail + "' AND password = '" + pass + "';";
    Cursor c = db.query(ConstantsBD.TABLA_EMPLEADOS, campos, where, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Empleados empleado = new Empleados();
            empleado.setId(c.getInt(0));
            empleado.setMail(c.getString(1));
            empleado.setPass(c.getString(2))
            demases datos de tu objeto
            list.add(empleado);
        }
    } finally { c.close(); }
    this.closeDB();
    return list;
}
```

Luego, crearía un `Array` solo con el mail:

```
public ArrayList datos(String mail) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.openReadableDB();
    String[] campos = new String[]{ConstantsBD.EMP_ID, ConstantsBD.EMP_MAIL, ConstantsBD.EMP_PASS, demases datos};
    String where = ConstantsBD.EMP_NOM + " = '" + mail + "';";
    Cursor c = db.query(ConstantsBD.TABLA_EMPLEADOS, campos, where, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Empleados empleado = new Empleados();
            empleado.setId(c.getInt(0));
            empleado.setMail(c.getString(1));
            empleado.setPass(c.getString(2))
            demases datos de tu objeto
            list.add(empleado);
        }
    } finally { c.close(); }
    this.closeDB();
    return list;
}
```

Para así crear un método que valide todo lo que necesito:

```
        private void validacionMailyPass(String user, String password){
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL(); //traemos la clase SQLite
            var caracteres = Convert.ToString(password); //creamos una var que nos cuente los caracteres
            var datoUSuario = conexionSQL.datos(user); 
            var usuario = conexionSQL.login(user, password);

            if(datoUSuario.Count > 0) //verificamos que haya por lo menos un usuario
            {
                if (datoUSuario[0].Contrasena == caracteres)//preguntamos si la contraseña es igual a los caracteres
                {
                    //Entonces al traer un usuario y que la contraseña es correcta
                    //el logueo es exitoso Toast.makeText(bla, "Login exitoso", Toast.etc).show();
                }
                else//si la contraseña es incorrecta
                {
                    //Toast con el error 
                    //tuEditTextContraseña.setText("");
                    //tuEditTextContraseña.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            else //si el array te trae un 0 entonces el mail no existe
            {
                //Toast con el error
                tuEditTextUsuario.setText("");
                tuEditTextUsuario.requestFocus();
            }
        }
```

Y luego a ese método lo introduces donde sea que lo necesites :)